# Make reading more comfortable for the eyes

Tags: fonts, display

First, I read the topics about displays. Sadly the "BenQ FP241WZ" is a no go, for ~715 eur it's way too much. I would need some ideas about how could I make reading less tiring.

Basically I didn't have this problem back then. But now, I'm reading some books, and also, have to read a lot a day. (A LOT). I look like some hardcore 0-24 gamer when I "finish" :).

Think about things like.. background color (like I read 'dark yellow' color + black tint helps), font size, fonts (!) cleartype settings (should be off?) and so on.

Display: BenQ E2200 HD (yeah cheap, eek, etc. Poor-man's LCD. :))
My CRT display is far away at the minute. So that is out of question. Also, my ThinkPad is here (T500), but I don't know about it's display. It comes with 1280x800 resolution and that's all I know (you can search back from that the FRU number, but I couldn't find it now).

What could I do? (Or basically everyone in such a situation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few common things:
1. CRT is very harsh on eyes, stick with LCD.
2. Make sure the LCD resolution is set to the native resolution of the display. This is usually the max, but not not always.
3. White lettering on a very dark (like navy blue, but not black) background is the easiest on your eyes.
4. Make sure you have other lights in the area on, eyes don't like staring at high-contrast (ie. staring at SU in the middle of the night with all the lights turned out).
5. Be sure the text is large enough for your eyesight (try changing the DPI settings if not; don't change the resolution, it makes everything fuzzy). 
6. If you have glasses, you should probably be wearing them. If you think you might need glasses, you probably do, go see an optomologist.

Comment: 2. Yes its on 1920x1080@60hz,32bpp | 3. Nice, I'll try that. | 4. Yeah i always cared about that, always using lights in the room, etc. | 5. Nice idea. | 6. Don't have glasses and I don't think I would need them. (My 'sight' is clear and perfect. Only this makes it really tired.)

Answer (score 0):

Benq E2200 HD isn't that bad. As for making it comfortable for reading, I've observed that a dark back ground ( black background with white text) - makes it really easy on the eyes.

Keep the monitor at its native resolution (ie, the Benq has a native resolution at 1920x1080 ). If you're going for a resolution other than a native resolution ensure that you maintain the same aspect ratio.

ClearType settings tend to be subjective - each person has their own views but I *like* having 
ClearType enabled.

And oh yes, keep the brightness and contrast down to reasonable levels, that will reduce eye fatigue **a lot**.